# Release and Reuse Shader Program Handles

Tags: c++, opengl-es

I have several shader programs in my engine, wich depends on the models I load (lambert, blinn, diffuse plain...). Everything works fine, but, when I reload the models, the shader indexes increases, to a point my hardware refuses the index.

> ...Linking [3] : Basic Blue
>
> ...Linking [6] : Basic Red
>
> ...Linking [9] : Basic Green

after reloading :

> ...Linking [30] : Basic Blue
>
> ...Linking [33] : Basic Red
>
> ...Linking [36] : Basic Green

the last shader I load should have ID 27. So, on reloading, the shader is compiled into the next ID's. (28 vertex shader, 29 fragment shader, 30 compiled program).

When I reload the models, I clear (better said, I think I clear) the shaders.

```
glDeleteProgram(programID);
```

But the Id's keep increasing like the id's are not released. Just in case the ID's are still on use by other things, like textures or vbos, I clear the textures:

```
glDeleteTextures(1,&handle);
```

And the VBOs.

```
glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertexVBOID);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &indexVBOID);
```

But they keep shader IDs keep increasing.

1. Is there something I might be missing?
2. How do I release the IDs?
3. How can I check wich kind of object holds the id?

Comment: cause when I execute the program on a resource limited Harware, the ID's goes to a illegal number, and the shaders starts to be refused."the shader indexes increases, to a point my hardware refuses the index."

Comment: Have you actually observed that? What hardware was that? What number was deemed illegal? Also, you need `glDeleteShader` as well as `glDeleteProgram`.

Comment: Raspberry Pi, and LG7. Around 120 (I suppose 127 is the key)

Comment: I delete the shaders after compilation. Is it good?

Comment: Yes. Programs use reference counting to keep shaders alive. This sounds like a veeeery bad driver, but I'd verify with a GL call log first. Are you able to obtain a trace of your OpenGL program listing every call? This should help you ensure you indeed delete everything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82194/discussion-between-bartek-banachewicz-and-diego-martinez).